# How to hide items after refiling to a collapsed target in org-mode?

Tags: org-mode

When an item is refiled to a target which is collapsed and contains other items, the refiled items are visible beneath the collapsed target. I would like these refiled items to instead be hidden along with the other items within the collapsed target.

So instead of:
 * Target...
 ** Refiled item 1
 ** Refiled item 2

one would just see:
* Target...

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Of course! Everything is possible in Emacs!

**Edit: revised solution**

If the collapsed status of the parent is all that you want to preserve, then maybe something like the following would be adequate:

```
(defun my/org-refile-preserve-collapsed-parent ()
  (org-up-heading-safe)
  (when (save-excursion
          (end-of-line)
          (org-invisible-p))
    (outline-hide-subtree)))

(add-hook 'org-after-refile-insert-hook #'my/org-refile-preserve-collapsed-parent)
```

**original solution**

The easiest solution would probably be just to advise `org-paste-subtree` (*this doesn't quite work*):

```
(defun my-advice/org-save-outline-visibility (orig-fun &rest args)
  (org-save-outline-visibility t
    (apply orig-fun args)))

(advice-add 'org-paste-subtree :around #'my-advice/org-save-outline-visibility)
```

If you don't want to have permanent advice on `org-paste-subtree` you could advise `org-refile` that adds and removes the advice for `org-paste-subtree`.

Comment: This solution is close. If the refile target is hidden within another collapsed heading, the parent heading remains collapsed (which I do want).  If the refile target is visible, however, the refiled item is still displayed beneath the collapsed target item, as in my first example.

Comment: @MaxPfleger Darn!  Outline visibility is tricky-- especially in this case when you're potentially refiling multiple headings.  I looked into using `org-after-refile-insert-hook` with the region delimiters which appear to still reflect the inserted text.  I ran into issues trying to use `(outline-flag-region (region-beginning) (region-end) t)` with outline visibility breaking in the document.

Comment: That's great! Your revised solution is exactly what I was looking for. I have come across one small glitch. If you undo a refile, the heading beneath the target heading moves up beside the target target. So it looks like `* Heading 1...* Heading 2` all in one line.

Comment: @MaxPfleger Interesting.  Maybe it just undoes the part of `org-paste-subtree` that shifts the outline level?  Was the refiled subtree ("Heading 2") originally a level 1 heading?

Comment: The undo behaviour seems to happen for all levels of headings. It is actually more than just a visual issue. The result of undoing a refile seems to confuse org-mode and lock that node so that it cannot be expanded. Expanding all the buffer's collapsed nodes corrects the problem.

Comment: I upgraded to emacs 26.1. Undo no longer locks the node and toggling visibility for the target node corrects the indentation problem. I noticed that refiling to a hidden node and undoing does not cause the problem. It is only when the target node is visible that the error occurs.